# Make Bitmap rendering faster

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm trying to convert an array of bytes to `Bitmap` image using following code:

```
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tilePage))
                g.Clear(Color.Black);

            for (int i = 0; i + offset < ROM.Length && i < tilePage.Height; i++)
            {
                int I = i * tilePage.Width + offset; //+Offset;
                for (int j = 0; j < tilePage.Width; j++)
                {
                    if (I + j >= ROM.Length)
                        goto finishRender;
                    tilePage.SetPixel(j, i, RPallete.getColor(ROM[I + j]));
                }
            }

        finishRender:
            picTileView.Image = tilePage;
```

but it renders too slow (2-3 seconds for 256*512 resolution). How to make it faster for example as in TileLayer?

P.S.: Sorry for bad English...

Answer (score -1):

You can use pointer. I used recently this code. You can improve as you wish

1. add picturebox that named pctResim
2. Check allow unsafe on project properties

Try this :

```
byte siyah=0;  
    int dizisayisi;    
    IntPtr baslangic;  
    byte[] rgbdeger;  
    Bitmap resim;   
    Rectangle rct;  
    BitmapData bmData;   
    resim = new Bitmap(@"C:\YazilimGrubu.jpg");
    rct = new Rectangle(0, 0, resim.Width, resim.Height);
    bmData = resim.LockBits(rct, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, resim.PixelFormat);
    baslangic = bmData.Scan0;
    dizisayisi = bmData.Stride * resim.Height;   
    rgbdeger = new byte[dizisayisi];   
    Marshal.Copy(baslangic, rgbdeger, 0, dizisayisi);
    for (int i = 2; i < rgbdeger.Length; i += 3)
    {
    siyah = (Byte)Math.Abs((Byte.Parse(rgbdeger[i - 2].ToString()) + Byte.Parse(rgbdeger[i - 1].ToString()) + Byte.Parse(rgbdeger[i].ToString())) / 3);
    rgbdeger[i - 2] = siyah;
    rgbdeger[i - 1] = siyah;
    rgbdeger[i] = siyah;
    }
    Marshal.Copy(rgbdeger, 0, baslangic, dizisayisi);
    resim.UnlockBits(bmData);
    pctResim.Image = resim;
```